# How to split whitespaces along with the following character in python

Tags: python, pandas, split, openpyxl

I'm using pandas, trying to text-to-column by splitting column(Teams) into Home and Away, but I am getting the following error:

```
"ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"
```

I was able to split the Score column as it only had '-' one delimiter, which was pretty easy. Not sure how to go about splitting the Teams column, as I was trying to use the space ' ' together with the 'v' character. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[Here is the sample data I'm working with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgfuB.png)

```
df = pd.read_excel('esports.xlsx')
#df.head()
#df[['score','oscore']] = df.Score.str.split("-",expand=True)
df[['team','opp']] = df.Teams.str.split((" "+"v"),expand=True)
df.head()
```

Comment: hi, it would be helpful if u shared actual data and not pics or a link to the data. [helpful guide](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+stack+overflow+minimal+example&oq=pandas+stack+over&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0j69i59j0j69i60l3j69i65.6155j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df[['team','opp']] = df.Teams.str.split(" v ",expand=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The split should be done using the patter " v " or maybe "\s+v\s+". Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
            ["TeamA v Teamb"],
            ["TeamA v Teamb"],
            ["TeamA v Teamb"],
])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Teams"])

df[["TeamA", "TeamB"]] = df.Teams.str.split("\s+v\s+", expand = True)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
           Teams  TeamA  TeamB
0  TeamA v Teamb  TeamA  Teamb
1  TeamA v Teamb  TeamA  Teamb
2  TeamA v Teamb  TeamA  Teamb
```

Comment: Yess! That worked perfect.
\s : If UNICODE is set, this will match the characters [ \t\n\r\f\v] plus whatever is classified as space in the Unicode character properties database.
Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the split function returns more or less than 2 columns. Can you check by running the following?

```
df.Teams.str.split((" "+"v"),expand=True)
```

If it returns more than 2 columns, you just need to extract the columns you need.